# Unity C# - Adding builtin arrays to List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
int[] trisFront = { 0, 3, 2,  2, 1, 0};
int[] trisRight = { 1, 2, 6,  6, 5, 1 };
int[] trisBack = { 5, 6, 7,  7, 4, 5 };
int[] trisLeft = { 4, 7, 3,  3, 0, 4 };
int[] trisUp = { 3, 7, 6,  6, 2, 3 };
int[] trisBottom = { 4, 0, 1,  1, 5, 4 };

List<int> tris = new List<int>();

tris.Add(trisFront);
tris.Add(trisBack);
tris.Add(trisRight);
tris.Add(trisLeft);
tris.Add(trisUp);
tris.Add(trisBottom);
```

I want all of trisBottom, Up... to be in tris list, how can I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear.. What is `tris`? What is the output you want?

Comment: public List<int> tris = new List<int>();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method you are adding 1 item of type `T` to a collection. Which in your current usage would mean that `tris` should be a `List<int[]>` because you are adding an item of type `int[]`.

What you should do is to use the [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `Add` - that will add all the items from the collections to the end of your `tris` list:

```
tris.AddRange(trisFront);
tris.AddRange(trisBack);
tris.AddRange(trisRight);
tris.AddRange(trisLeft);
tris.AddRange(trisUp);
tris.AddRange(trisBottom);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want [`List.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
tris.AddRange(trisFront);
```

Answer (score 0):

When tris is a GenericList you can just use:

```
tris.AddRange(trisFront);
```

In case it's a different DataType let me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public List<int> tris = new List<int>();

    int[] trisFront = { 0, 3, 2,  2, 1, 0};
    int[] trisRight = { 1, 2, 6,  6, 5, 1 };
    int[] trisBack = { 5, 6, 7,  7, 4, 5 };
    int[] trisLeft = { 4, 7, 3,  3, 0, 4 };
    int[] trisUp = { 3, 7, 6,  6, 2, 3 };
    int[] trisBottom = { 4, 0, 1,  1, 5, 4 };

    tris.AddRange(trisFront);
    tris.AddRange(trisBack);
    tris.AddRange(trisRight);
    tris.AddRange(trisLeft);
    tris.AddRange(trisUp);
    tris.AddRange(trisBottom);
```

Works perfectly

Comment: The correct thing to do, in the case that one of the answers helped you solve your problem is to accept that answer (instead of posting a new answer with the solution)